# Как проверить что все страницы сайта помещаются в экран?

Tags: html, css, адаптивная-верстка, тестирование

Есть список URL, нужно убедиться что на всех разрешениях экрана на этих страницах не появляется горизонтальный скролл. Каждая страница имеет разные стили для разных разрешений, их около десятка.

Comment: Если не вручную, то Selenium

Answer (score 0):

1. вручную всегда надежней
2. Сервисы вроде [этого](https://search.google.com/test/mobile-friendly), [этого](http://symby.ru/adaptest/) или [этого](http://adaptivator.ru)